# Using sed to scan c++ files

Tags: sed

I need to find all instances of "[0]" and "[1]" in several files ending in .cpp. The files are located in different sub directories.

Is it poissible to use sed to scan through all .cpp files in sub directories and look for a pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `grep` or `ack`?

Comment: Definitely a job for [tag:ack]. Or [tag:git]`-grep`.

Comment: As suggested, go for `grep -R "\[[01]\]" *` to scan all files, and if there are to many non-cpp files, append `| grep "\.cpp"`

Comment: `grep "\[[0-1]\]" **/*.cpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave `sed` alone, it's for **s**tream **ed**iting, not searching. Use `grep`.

```
find . -iname '*.cpp' | while read filename; do grep --with-filename '\[[01]\]' "$filename"; done
```

Or in a script:

```
find . -iname '*.cpp' | while read filename 
do 
    grep --with-filename '\[[01]\]' "$filename"
done
```

I'm using `read` here (and quotes around `$filename`) so that filenames with spaces in survive; in Windows systems this is a particular nightmare.

If you know none of your files are particularly big, you can sacrifice efficiency of search for efficiency of typing and search all the files but only pick out the output from cpp files:

```
grep -r '\[[01]\]' . | grep '.cpp:'
```